# Bootsrap can't be uploaded

Tags: bootstrap-4

Hello I am having issues installing bootstrap In a new website I do not understand why but when I go to the console it outputs this. It certainly has never happend to me before and I do not know how to sort it out

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('application/xml') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
2bootstrap.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
bootstrap.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

Comment: Could your share your html code where you've added the cdn link for Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it's because your bootstrap version is in beta, you should use the previous CDN, like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" >
```

This should be ok for now.

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing the same issue.

4.5 version seems to have a bug which doesn't allow us to apply the stylesheets in our HTML. Please use v4.4 instead.

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Bootstrap uses [StackPath](https://www.stackpath.com/) for CDN. I think it has something to do with Booststrap's configuration on StackPath.

The reason you get this specific error is that StackPath denies access (returns 403) and an XML formatted error explanation. Since XML is not a proper MIME type to apply as a stylesheet, your browser refuses to apply it and prompts an error message to console.

You can simply get over this issue by two different ways.

**Solution 1:**

If you HAVE TO use the latest version (4.5) of Bootstrap, you can go to the download section, [download the Compiled CSS and JS files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/#compiled-css-and-js), extract **bootstrap.min.css** and include it in your project.

**Solution 2**

If you don't need the latest version, simply just downgrade your version and use [version 4.4 of Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/). Since CDN for v4.4 works fine, you can copy the line below and include it on your project.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternate cdn for bootstrap.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```